# PHP Appending criteria to a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to use a prepared statement to search a db where I don't know how many arguments I need to search against. So the following example checks that column 'title' contains two variables

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT title FROM news WHERE title LIKE %?% AND title LIKE %?%");
```

What if I want to check against a third variable. Can I append to a prepared statement?
My only solution so far is as follows which is horrible as I don't know the maximum number of variables.

```
$no_of_variables = 3;

if($no_of_variables == 1){
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT title FROM news WHERE title LIKE %?%");
} else if($no_of_variables == 2){
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT title FROM news WHERE title LIKE %?% AND title LIKE %?%");
} else if($no_of_variables == 3){
    //etc
}
```

I'd be grateful for a better way using prepared statements if possible. Thanks

Comment: With prepared statements - you should use `LIKE ?` and add the `%` to the bind value (or use string concatenation in MySQL)

Comment: You can create string of an argument with , separator and then pass to your query with using ```IN``` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the prepared statement by repeating the condition `$no_of_variables`-times:

```
$where = implode(" AND ", array_fill(0, $no_of_variables, "title LIKE %?%"));
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT title FROM news WHERE {$where}");
```

Comment: I think your LIKE clause is broken.